# Transforming XML document to POJO

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I have a bunch of XML documents (source) which I need to transform into POJOs with a different structure (target). My first obvious idea was to use a combination of JAXB and XSLT. However there are some issues where I'm not sure if this is appropriate.

1. I don't have access to the XSD of the source.
2. I don't need the target as XML structure but just as POJOs.

Then I thought of creating something like a mapping table, like e.g.

```
XPath to source XML element --> Target element
```

However this would result in a lot of "mapping" code, especially if complex data types are involved.

Do you have any advice how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest JSON.

You don't have to know the structure of your XML in advance.  Just suck your XML into a DOM object or SAX stream, traverse it and spit out the equivalent JSON objects.  XSLT will work nicely too.

Here is a link with examples/discussios on how to load a JSON file into java objects.

[load json from file into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005767/load-json-from-file-into-object#11005797)

I suspect that programatically it's about the same effort to handle an XML document as it is a JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a representative XML document that shows all of the possible sub-elements comprising the domain of the XML document (for example, if there are any CHOICE elements in the XML document, you have representative XML elements that show all possible CHOICE paths), then you can simply use a tool like XML Spy to reverse-engineer/infer the schema from the representative XML file, and then use that inferred schema to drive JAX-B.